# Gremlin - AWS Neptune - issue when Order by property which does not exist on a vertex

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

```
g.V().hasLabel('Asset').order().by('anyprop',decr).valueMap(true)
```

sometimes it throws error:

```
UnsupportedOperationException\",\"detailedMessage\":\"Encountered a traverser that does not map to a value for child traversal: value(anyprop)
```

my guess is there are some vertex does not have 'anyprop' property.

I dynamically generate the query, so 'anyprop' could be any property, how do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Neptune moves up to the 3.5.x Apache TinkerPop level there are some changes to the way Gremlin handles cases like this that will stop the error from happening. In the near term, you can just use a `coalesce` to sort by a default value in cases where the key does not exist. Note I changed `decr` to `desc` as `decr` is deprecated now.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Asset').
      order().
        by(coalesce(values('anyprop'),constant(0)),desc).
      valueMap(true).limit(3)
```